# run python file from different directory including sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, exe, node-red

This code runs perfectly fine if I first redirect to the folder where this main.py file is located. So in cmd I just type: python main.py. In this folder is also my database "Datalog.db" located.

If I run this python file from somewhere else, I get a problem with this line of code: cur.execute(sql). So in cmd I type: python C:\Users\ [...] \main.py. I get following error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Datalog". Later I want to include this python file in a pythonshell in node-red and there I have to define the full path of this main.py

I also tried to build an exe-file with it but then the same error occurs:"sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Datalog".

Apparently the connection to the database is not the issue, first my cur.execute command is not working.

I find out that I have to "include my SQLite database file in the include_files statement", but I have no idea how to do this ..

Can anybody help? I am very sorry for any inconvenience, I just started programming and this is my first post.

```py
import sqlite3 as db

db_name = 'Datalog'
output_number = 'Output1'
output = 'hello'
timestamp = '2019-11-11 09:27:02'
db_name = f'{db_name}.db'

con = db.connect(db_name)
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()

sql = f"UPDATE Datalog SET {output_number}='{output}' WHERE timestamp ='{timestamp}'"

cur.execute(sql)
con.commit()
print("### DB updated ###")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change db_name to the full path of your sqlite database or even better, dynamically build the path to the db (Below code assumes the db is in the same folder (directory) as the file which calls the below code ):

```
import os.path

db_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__filename__)) + 'Datalog'
```

Comment: perfect, this completly solved my problem way easier than I tried to solve it, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

python looks for files in "sys.path" so you want to insert the name of the directory containing your file in that path so python can find it
here is an example:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\Philip\Work\Bin')
```

where 0 is the position in the sys.path, 0 means top, 1 means second from top etc.
obviously you would replace my directory with yours